# Orchard CMS: programmatically get elements of custom content part

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, orchardcms

I'm creating module for Orchard CMS - viewer widget for elements of custom ContentType.

So, I have interface for service:

```
public interface IReviewGrabber : IDependency 
{
    IEnumerable<ReviewPart> Reviews { get; }
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
public class ReviewGrabber : IReviewGrabber
{
    readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;
    readonly IEnumerable<ReviewPart> _reviews;

    public ReviewGrabber(IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    {
        _orchardServices = orchardServices;
        var temp = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<ReviewPart, ReviewRecord>();
        _reviews = temp.List();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReviewPart> Reviews
    {
        get { return _reviews; }
    }
}
```

And handler for ContentType:

```
public class ReviewHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public ReviewHandler(IRepository<ReviewRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

Debugging this, I've added element of type Review manually, and it works. In `ReviewGrabber` class variable `temp` fills correctly, but calling method `List()` for it fires error:

**ValueFactory tries to access the Value property of this instance.**

**_handlers.Value   '_handlers.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable {System.InvalidOperationException}**

on row

```
public IEnumerable<IContentHandler> Handlers {
     get { return _handlers.Value; }
}
```

in `DefaultContentManager.cs`

What's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, doing a query in a constructor is a big no-no. Constructors should only do trivial work such as initialize variables, not query databases.

Property getters, similarly, should usually not do a lot of work. You should be using a method, GetReviews, that does the querying as needed. Caching can be added later if necessary.